# Call to a member function getDateFormat() on null, laravel/passport install

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5, laravel-passport

I am getting a

```
  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError] Call to a member function getDateFormat() on null
```

when running "php artisan passport:install" on a laravel/mongodb api project. I have tried changing "use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;" to "use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Model;" in my user and client.php but it still throws the exception.

any ideas??

Comment: What is your artisan command trying to do? Share some code.

Comment: Hi Niraj, thanks for your response. I was installing laravel/passport so the command was "php artisan passport: install" and that is the error I get.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem while developing a same type of project. This occurs because Laravel Passport doesn't support Jenssegres\laravel-mongodb. It uses the Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model by default.

Now there are two solutions to this.

1. You can go on changing every **Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model** to **Jenssegres\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model** in the Laravel Passport's vendor folder(there are about 6 files you will have to change), but this is not recommended, as when you will try you push this project on the production server, the vendor folder is ignored, and you will have to do all the changes again. Also if they change something and you update it, all the changes will be lost.
2. Another way of doing this, which I would recommend is, using **designmynight/laravel-mongodb-passport** package. This package will do the above-stated things and will do it efficiently. Installation is also pretty simple. You can go through the documentation [here](https://github.com/designmynight/laravel-mongodb-passport) and you can have it up and running in no time.

Hope this can solve your problem.

*Documentation link: https://github.com/designmynight/laravel-mongodb-passport*